# Deploying Meteor App Using Script

Tags: node.js, meteor

How can we create the meteor deploying script. Currently we need to enter following command manually for deploying the app -

- **Meteor login** (After pressing the enter, It will ask username and
  password of galaxy server account)
- After login, We need to use command
  '**DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com meteor deploy ***.meteorapp.com
  --settings localhost.com.json**' for deploying the app.

How to make simple shell script for above commands?

Comment: It seems not over complicated, where do you get stuck?

Comment: shell should remember login credentials. I have a batch script in Windows for that.

Comment: @TGrif actually I tried but how to put username and password automatically through script .did you know about it?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should create meteor session file:

```
METEOR_SESSION_FILE=meteor-login.json meteor login
```

After successful login the `meteor-login.json` file will be created and it could be used later to deploy to the same account without the need to manually enter login/password.

Now, you can write `sh` script to deploy:

```
#!/bin/sh
METEOR_SESSION_FILE=meteor-login.json DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com meteor deploy <server> --settings <path-to-settings-file>
```

Don't forget to replace `<server>` and `<path-to-settings-file>` with actual values.